# How to query overpass turbo using > and < operators?

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, overpass-api

I want to use [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) to query data within a certain range of numerical attribute values. For example, I want to find `power=line` elements with `voltage` in a range between 100kV and 200kV.

I would have expected that a query like this

```
way
  [power=line]
  [voltage>100000]
  [voltage<200000]
  ({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

would yield such results. But in this case I receive the error message,

> parse error: '!', '~', '=', '!=', or ']' expected - '<' found.

so I presume that `>` and `<` operators are not allowed here. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Overpass GitHub](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/78), there has already been a request for using those operators directly.

However, you can use a regular expression to obtain voltage between 100kV and 200kV:

```
way
  [power=line]
  [voltage~"^[1][0-9]{5}$"]
  ({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

---

[image: Overpass]